# accordion not working with Update panel

Tags: c#, jquery, updatepanel

I am creating a child page using the master page. The Content Place Holder in the master page is inside and Update panel like below

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="MainUpdatePanel">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cphMain" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

On my child page I have Jquery accordion. One of the accordion panel has a button, But when I click on the button the child page style is not working.

Comment: what you are doing with button in accordian? any post back or what?

Comment: Yes the button will do a post back.

Comment: No I am not using any scripts in the child page.

Comment: you have used script to master page for accordian? then plz past the code also

Comment: Script I used in this  $("#accordion").accordion({ heightStyle: "content" });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this script Like

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
        function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
            if (args.get_error() == undefined) {
                $(function () {
                    //Your script
                });
            }
        }
    </script>
```

This will not work on post back that your update panel is giving to you.

Comment: If you are using accordion to child panel only then put that script to child panel only rather then using it to master page.

Comment: always use the script wherever you have put the script item not to the parent pages as it will gives you the errors if it will not found the element